# Error: "Assembly with name 'UnityEditor.StandardEvents' already exists (Packages/com.unity.standardevents/Editor/Editor.asmdef)"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I just updated my unity to 2018.1.0f2 and it is giving me this error:
"Assembly with name 'UnityEditor.StandardEvents' already exists (Packages/com.unity.standardevents/Editor/Editor.asmdef)"
Any idea what I should be doing to avoid this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove all foder in project but keep folder asset and project setting, *.sln

Comment: This worked for me
My error occurred because I had a folder named "Assets" inside the "Assets" folder
which made Unity think that inner Assets folder is the actual folder
and made library and other folders inside Assets folder
I just deleted those and changed the name of my folder
and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, and solved it with the following steps:

1. Uninstall unity
2. Open this path

   > C:\Users(name of your account)\AppData\Local\Unity

Remove all folders and files

3. Install unity

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue:

- I opened folder C:\ProgramData\Unity\cache\npm
- Then inside, removed every folder other than packages.unity.com